# Grant Access to biztalk application user group to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, biztalk

I want to grant access to a Biztalk application user group to SQL Server database

```
use[mydatabase]

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = (select @@SERVERNAME)+N'\BizTalk Application Users')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [Domain\BizTalk Application Users']FOR LOGIN [Domain\BizTalk Application Users]
END;
GO

ALTER USER [Domain\BizTalk Application Users] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
ALTER ROLE [db_roleAppUser] ADD MEMBER [Domain\BizTalk Application Users]
GO
```

I want to replace my domain with `select @@SERVERNAME` so that I can run this script in deployment framework.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @login NVARCHAR(50),@sql NVARCHAR(max);
SET @login = (SELECT @@SERVERNAME)+N'\BizTalk Application Users'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = (SELECT @@SERVERNAME)+N'\BizTalk Application Users')
BEGIN
     SET @sql = N'CREATE USER [' + @login + N'] FOR LOGIN [' + @login + N'];'
     EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END;
GO
DECLARE @login NVARCHAR(50),@sql NVARCHAR(max);
SET @login = (SELECT @@SERVERNAME)+N'\BizTalk Application Users'
SET @sql = N'ALTER USER [' + @login + N']  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO
DECLARE @login NVARCHAR(50),@sql NVARCHAR(max);
SET @login = (SELECT @@SERVERNAME)+N'\BizTalk Application Users'
SET @sql = N'ALTER ROLE [db_roleAppUser] ADD MEMBER [' + @login + N']'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO
```